# Subtract total sum of a colum, From the total sum of a colum from another table

Tags: mysql

I'm wondering the subtraction total sum of `amount_no` column of table2 from total sum of `amount_no` table1.

```
   table1                           table2
   |amount_no |                     |amount_no|
   ------------                     -----------
   |230       |                     |100      |
   |500       |                     |50       |
   |700       |                     |40       |
   ------------                     ----------
   1430                             190
   ------------                     ----------
              (1430 - 190 = 1240)
```

```
SELECT ((SUM(amount_no) FROM table1) - (SELECT SUM(amount_no) FROM table2))
```

Comment: Is your query not working?

Comment: @apokryfos not working

Comment: are there any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated query:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(amount_no) FROM table1) - (SELECT SUM(amount_no) FROM table2)
```

Your code have missing some brackets.

Comment: it isnt showing correct result....  $sql="SELECT (SELECT SUM(amount_no) FROM table1) - (SELECT SUM(amount_no) FROM table2WHERE subDate` BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to')";

Comment: @explorer104: Please also provide database table which you have used.

Comment: @explorer104: Try this one:   $sql="SELECT (SELECT SUM(amount_no) FROM table1) - (SELECT SUM(amount_no) FROM table2 WHERE subDate BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to')";

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(amount_no) FROM table1) - (SELECT SUM(amount_no) FROM table2)
```

Your code misses the select part and minor things.

Comment: it is not showing the correct result .                                                          `$sql="SELECT (SELECT SUM(amount_no) FROM table1) - (SELECT SUM(amount_no) FROM table2WHERE `subDate` BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to')";`